# Lemons and lemonade

Tags: discussion

With regards to this recent question:

[A sandwich function](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/45629/1993)

I do think there's a disconnect when the question gets -4 and the answer gets +3. It encourages people to answer.

Over on MathOverflow we at times had the idea of turning lemons into lemonade. That is, when the question is too easy, but you feel the urge to answer it, think of something related that is interesting and research level, and put that in an answer. Without just answering homework level questions directly.

[An example](https://mathoverflow.net/a/287927/4600)

Any pros and cons?

Comment: Can you think of examples of this from MO? It may be good to see one for context.

Comment: @SashoNikolov I added an example although there are better ones

Comment: An old meta question asking essentially the same: https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1015/finding-negation-of-regular-expression-too-basic/